# Create tests to cover cases where the response from the third-party API is not the expected response

Tags: python, api, testing, pytest

I have an API on Flask (Python) that interacts with a third-party API, for example, creating documents.
My code:

```
def my_function(data):
    response = requests.post("https://some_api.com", json=data)
    json_response = response.json()
    if json_response["message"] == "Successfully created":
        return "Successfully created"
    elif json_response["message"] == "Already exists":
        return "Already exists"
    elif json_response["message"] == "Wrong data":
        return "Wrong data"
    else:
        return json_response["message"]
```

I have already created tests to cover cases where the third-party API works as expected(where "message" equals to "Successfully created", "Already exists" or "Wrong data").
However, I also want to cover case where the third-party API does not work as expected. I want to create a test that covers the 'else' branch, but I cannot reach it while the third-party API is working properly.
Is there a way to obtain a response that the third-party API would not normally provide?
Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How would you achieve it if it was your own code instead of third party?

Comment: You would need to show us both the test you're trying to write and the code under test. Generally, the answer is "write a test that delivers an invalid response to your code, and then verify the error is handled as you expect".

Comment: @larsks Updated the post with example of my code.   
The problem is that I want to create a test that covers the 'else' branch, but I cannot reach it while the third-party API is working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically use a [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) to replace your interaction with the actual API with synthesized behavior that you control.

For example, in the following code we're using `mock.patch("requests.post")` (where `mock.patch` comes from the [`unittest` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)) so that calling `requests.post` doesn't actually make an HTTP request to a remote site; instead `requests.post` -- while inside our test function -- is a fake object for which we can control the return value and other aspects:

```
import pytest
import requests
from unittest import mock


def my_function(data):
    response = requests.post("https://some_api.com", json=data)
    json_response = response.json()
    if json_response["message"] == "Successfully created":
        return "Successfully created"
    elif json_response["message"] == "Already exists":
        return "Already exists"
    elif json_response["message"] == "Wrong data":
        return "Wrong data"
    else:
        return json_response["message"]


@mock.patch("requests.post")
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "json_response,expected_return",
    [
        ({"message": "Successfully created"}, "Successfully created"),
        ({"message": "Already exists"}, "Already exists"),
        ({"message": "Wrong data"}, "Wrong data"),
        ({"message": "Some other message"}, "Some other message"),
    ],
)
def test_my_function_suceeds(mock_post, json_response, expected_return):
    mock_response = mock.MagicMock()
    mock_response.json.return_value = json_response
    mock_post.return_value = mock_response
    res = my_function("")
    assert res == expected_return
```

This is a [parametrized](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html) test, meaning that while we have a single test function, `pytest` will run it multiple times for each set of parameters. Running this with `pytest -v` yields:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.1, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /home/lars/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-LD_ZK5QN/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python
plugins: anyio-3.6.2, base-url-2.0.0, playwright-0.3.0
collecting ... collected 4 items

testex.py::test_my_function_suceeds[json_response0-Successfully created] PASSED [ 25%]
testex.py::test_my_function_suceeds[json_response1-Already exists] PASSED [ 50%]
testex.py::test_my_function_suceeds[json_response2-Wrong data] PASSED    [ 75%]
testex.py::test_my_function_suceeds[json_response3-Some other message] PASSED [100%]
============================== 4 passed in 0.04s ===============================
```

This is actually a bit more complicated than necessary, since in all cases your `my_function` function is simply returning the value of the `message` key, so we could in fact have written our test like this:

```
@mock.patch("requests.post")
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "message",
    [
        "Successfully created",
        "Already exists",
        "Wrong data",
        "Some other message",
    ],
)
def test_my_function_suceeds(mock_post, message):
    mock_response = mock.MagicMock()
    mock_response.json.return_value = {"message": message}
    mock_post.return_value = mock_response
    res = my_function("")
    assert res == message
```

But I think the first example is more representative of how you would normally write this, since it's unlikely most functions would have such trivial behavior.